Why is there weird behaviour in the display of shaders when using bent geometry with straight UVs?
I tried something rather simple and was confused by the result.
I created a straight plane 
Added 3 cuts, then UV unwrapped it:

After that I proceeded to rotate the points to get a 90° bend, keeping the UVs straight:

I then added a simple shader to the mesh that, via the color ramp slider, moves the black part on the Y of the UV. This should allow me to switch from white to black:

Now for the weird part I dont understand. I move the gradient, so the plane should get black from top to bottom, around the corner then to the right, as the UVs are straight.

On the straight unbent part everything is as expected, but as soon as the gradient hits a bent part this happens:



As you can see the gradient border is bent. As the UV's are straight I would think that there shouldn't be any extra corners or so in the border from black to white.
I have no idea why this is happening.
And the only "solution" to the problem I found so far: Adding a subdivision surface modifier set to simple and increasing the levels:

As you can see this "straightens" the border and it behaves as expected. Though in "lower" subdivision levels there still is some weird "anti aliasing" going on. This improves if you increase the levels, but this seems like a bad workaround that only works on simple meshes.
Can anyone explain why this is happening? Of course a fix to this problem would also be appreciated.
Thanks!
Daniel

In short, you are deforming your original shape and thus the UVs does not match anymore. Instead of that, use bones to deform your mesh

@Emir, would shape keys work? I guess bones will be too much work compared.

No, I don't think it will work (not a 100% sure). Bones for simple shapes are really simple to setup

This is happening because quads are made of 2 tris, so as soon as you deform your quads you'll see the inner triangulation, you have no other choice but to subdivide your object.
